# What is the translation of the following citation

Tags: english-to-german

Recently, I found a citation in a signature of someone on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Feature/HallOfShame.aspx?msg=4282328#xx4282328xx):

> As programmers go, I'm fairly social. Which still means I'm a
>   borderline sociopath by normal standards.

I would translate this into the following:

> Für Programmiererverhältnisse bin ich recht sozial. Was noch immer
>   bedeutet, dass ich ein Borderline-Soziopath bin unter normalen
>   Standards/Gesichtspunkten.

Especially the first part (As programmers go) keeps me thinking. If I translate this more word-by-word, this results in "Wenn Programmierer gehen..." but I would never translate this German back into the cited English "As programmers go". So probably I'm totally wrong. What is the translation of this citation in German?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are right in that "wenn Programmierer gehen" is not a proper translation of that phrase. Your proposed translation is actually ok. However because the word "Programmiererverhältnisse" is quite clunky I'd use the following way:

> Für einen Programmierer bin ich recht sozial.

The word "borderline" does exist in German but I only know it from the borderline syndrome which is probably not what is meant here. I'd rather say

> Was bedeutet, dass ich für normale Verhältnisse immer noch an der Grenze zum Soziopathen bin.

Comment: +1 for "Für einen Programmierer..." it doesn't get much more idiomatic - this is *the* phrase for "As xx go..." :)

Comment: And the inevitable silent downvote. I don't have a problem with having someone disagree with me but without an explanation it's just not helpful. How can I improve?!

Comment: @musiKk So, you know it wasn't me, but I have an opinion. And if I'm right, read your two translations parts **together** and think why that does not sound German ;) And if you come to the conclusion to edit your answer, yeah, follow the translation rule: "So viel wie nötig, so wenig wie möglich!"

Comment: I think the second part would sound more idiomatic if it had a negation: *Was aber nicht heißt, dass ich für normale Verhältnisse nicht immer noch an der Grenze zum Soziopathen bin.*

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is:

> Was Programmierer angeht, bin ich (noch) recht gesellschaftsfähig. Das ändert aber nichts an der Tatsache, dass ich aus der Sicht anderer (immer noch) an der Grenze zum Soziopathen bin.

I'm afraid I couldn't offer a different ending to musiKk translation without loosing too much content. Maybe you can shorten it to "verrückt" (in its colloquial meaning, not regarding the insanity) or what Germans like to say: "Kellerkind".

> ..., dass ich aus der Sicht anderer verrückt bin.
>
> ..., dass ich aus der Sicht anderer dennoch ein Kellerkind bin.

Comment: I think your suggestions are very loose. They barely resemble the structure and wording of the original sentences. In itself, the phrases are fine, but they don't really work as translations.

Comment: @musiKk Naja, ich seh das aus ner anderen Sicht. Solange es hier nicht um ein Gedicht oder so geht, versuche ich gar nicht den englischen Wortlaut zu folgen. Ich übersetze eher: Verstehe den englischen Text und gibt es in deutschen Worten wieder. (Was du übrgens auch gemacht hast, nur hast du andere Worte gewählt. Einzig "sozial" finde ich wirklich unschön, da es für gewöhnlich eher für "soziales Engangement" verwendet wird, dennoch +1)

Comment: a) Ist `gesellschaftsfähig` oder `gesellig` gemeint? Das m.E. einfältige und gehässige Klischee vom Programmierer lautet doch nicht, dass er nicht weiß dass man sich beim Husten die Hand vor den Mund hält, sondern dass er gar nicht erst raus geht. Als Programmierer kenne ich viele Programmierer, und davon sind manche nicht sonderlich gesellig - aber unter den Nichtprogrammierern sind vielleicht genausoviele ungesellig. Man kann nat. einen systematischen Fehler annehmen, weil man ungesellige P. kaum kennenlernt. :)

Comment: b) Die Frage dreht sich aber doch v.a. um das `As programmers go, ...`, nicht um den zweiten Teil.

Answer (score 0):

Folgende Formulierungen fallen mir ein:

- Was Programmierer betrifft ...
- Gemessen an anderen Programmierern ...
- Verglichen mit anderen Programmierern bin ich ...
- Im Falle von Programmierern ...

Generell lehne ich die unbedachte Übernahme solcher Klischees ab, und würde anderen dazu raten mir nachzueifern.

- Gemessen am Klischee vom Programmierer ...
- Abweichend zu verbreiteten Vorurteilen über Programmierer ...
- Verglichen mit dem, was Sie vielleicht über P. gehört haben ...
- Im Kontrast zur schablonenhaften Idee vom Programmierer als Soziopath (greife ich gleich zur Kettensäge wenn mich jmd. freundlich anspricht ...)